# Quit reading an erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Is there a way in ruby's ERBs (e.g. in a rails view) to quit parsing the file before the end is reached? Something in the direction of ruby's `__END__`.

```
Some Text
<%= ... %>
<% some_magic_quit_function %>
This will not be included in the result
```

I've tried `return` but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, but there's the much more straightforward

```
<% unless some_quit_function %>
  Output you don't want included if some_quit_function returns true
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Doug R pointed out this will not work, the reason being is that Erb evaluates the result of the method "some_magic_quit_function" and then returns the result as a render. I assume you have a return in that method, which all it does is return from that method itself (it doesn't return globally).

You will need to use the code (a logic test where you return in the actual Erb file) that Doug R has provided.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I assume it's because this is more like a comment on Doug's answer and not an answer by itself